# pulltorefresh.js - Disable temporarily

Tags: javascript, pull-to-refresh

I am using this PullToRefresh plugin:

https://github.com/BoxFactura/pulltorefresh.js#api

It works well but I have a popup on my page with div inline scroll.
The problem is that when I want to scroll up (in the div) the PullToRefresh is triggered. Is it possible to "delete" or to temporarily disable the PullToRefresh when my popup is opened?

```
PullToRefresh.init({
    mainElement: 'body',
    onRefresh: function(){
        refreshAll();
    }
});
```

edit:
`delete PullToRefresh;` // does not work

edit2:
https://github.com/BoxFactura/pulltorefresh.js/blob/master/dist/pulltorefresh.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PullToRefresh.init()` will return an object with a `destroy()` function as callback: https://github.com/BoxFactura/pulltorefresh.js/blob/master/dist/pulltorefresh.js#L326

```
var refresher = PullToRefresh.init({
    mainElement: 'body',
    onRefresh: function(){
        refreshAll();
    }
});

// destroy the PullToRefresh EventListeners when you open your popup
refresher.destroy()
```

There's also an open Github issue about improving the way to destroy this library after initialization: https://github.com/BoxFactura/pulltorefresh.js/issues/22

Answer (score 1):

IMO there are two *reasonable* ways to do this.

You can define a `triggerElement` and put your overlay outside of this triggerElement:

```
PullToRefresh.init({
    mainElement: 'body',
    triggerElement: '#mainContent',
    onRefresh: refreshAll
});
```

with a markup somewhat like this

```
<body>
    <div id="containerForOverlays"></div>
    <div id="mainContent"></div>
</body>
```

that way, everything inside of `#containerForOverlays` won't trigger a refresh.

---

Or you could use the new hook `shouldPullToRefresh()` if your version already supports it.

An example where `PullToRefresh` depends on a checkbox to be checked

```
<label><input id="refresh" type="checkbox"> Pull to Refresh?</label>
```

using it like

```
PullToRefresh.init({
    mainElement: 'body',
    shouldPullToRefresh: function(){
        return document.getElementById('pullToRefresh').checked
    },
    onRefresh: refreshAll
});
```

Of course I'm not suggesting that you use a checkbox in your production code. I just wanted to show how you could dynamically *"turn `PullToRefresh` on and off"*. In this example, depending on the checkbox to be checked.

It's up to you to implement the correct `shouldPullToRefresh()` for your application to determine wether `PullToRefresh` should be active or not.